# How is the NAND gate implemented? (Conceptually)

Tags: javascript, logic, bit-manipulation, circuit

I am trying to find the lowest level of things that you just *can't implement* because they are too low level. So it seems that all computation can be constructed from the [NAND gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAND_logic).

[image]

From the truth table it is easy to "implement" in JavaScript:

```
function nand(a, b) {
  if (a == 0 && b == 0) return 1
  if (a == 0 && b == 1) return 1
  if (a == 1 && b == 0) return 1
  if (a == 1 && b == 1) return 0
}
```

But this is cheating. Because how are the [IF statements implemented](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/15393/generic-method-for-implementing-if-else-statement-in-hardware-using-gates-mux-d)? I don't quite know how to represent that if-statement link in code since I'm not sure familiar with logic gates/circuits, but I am pretty sure the IF statement itself could be represented as a combination of NAND gates.

***So then it's turtles all the way down!** A NAND gate is implemented with more NAND gates (for the if-statements), etc..*

So how do we avoid this situation? Do we simply say that a NAND gate is an *axiom*? I am wondering because I'm wondering where the foundation for formal verification lies.

Put another way, the reason I'm asking is because I've noticed that every function can be implemented as other functions, even the IF statement and such. Everything can be implemented all the way down to NAND gates. But then I am left swinging, the NAND is a function too, but what is it's implementation?!? I'm confused/perplexed and need some guidance on how to think about this.

Comment: what type of input do you want?

Comment: You know I am not really sure, whatever input makes this possible to define, either as an axiom or not.

Comment: There is a bottom. Logic circuits in hardware are physical devices. You can keep stacking layers of "emulate NAND using more NANDs" on top, but the bottom is still there, just further away now. By the way JavaScript `if` statements work *completely differently* from `if` in pure digital logic.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Since NAND is Not AND you can declare it using AND, which means that NAND is not an axiom:

```js
function nand(a, b) {
  return !(a && b)
}

console.log(nand(false, false)) // true
console.log(nand(true, false)) // true
console.log(nand(false, true)) // true
console.log(nand(true, true)) // false
```

Using multiplication you can declare NAND with 0 and 1. Since AND is `a * b` (you get 1 if both are 1), NAND is `1 - a * b`:

```js
function nand(a, b) {
  return 1 - a * b
}

console.log(nand(0, 0)) // 1
console.log(nand(1, 0)) // 1
console.log(nand(0, 1)) // 1
console.log(nand(1, 1)) // 0
```